# Python SimPy: How to split or copy customers?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

Here is what I'm trying to implement in SimPy:

Customers firstly enter Server A for 5 minutes of service. Then each customer is split into two, one goes to Server B for 3 minutes of service, one goes to Server C for 2 minutes of service.

I wrote the following code but it seems not working based on the output. Also I'm not sure the way I use the copy function is correct, because I want to split EACH customer that is leaving Server A, but I feel my code may only work with the very first customer.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
from copy import *

class Source(Process):                               
    def generate(self):                 
        for i in range(5):
            c = Customer(name="Customer%02d" % (i))  
            activate(c, c.runA())
            yield hold, self, 10                    

class Customer(Process):
    def runA(self):
        print("%7.4f %s (original) enters server A" % (now(), self.name))
        yield hold, self, 5
        print("%7.4f %s (original) leaves server A" % (now(), self.name))

        dup1 = copy(self)
        dup2 = copy(self)
        activate(dup1, dup1.runB())
        activate(dup2, dup2.runC())

    def runB(self):
        print("%7.4f %s (copy) enters server B" % (now(), self.name))
        yield hold, self, 3
        print("%7.4f %s (copy) leaves server B" % (now(), self.name))

    def runC(self):
        print("%7.4f %s (copy) enters server C" % (now(), self.name))
        yield hold, self, 2
        print("%7.4f %s (copy) leaves server C" % (now(), self.name))

initialize()
s = Source()                                         
activate(s, s.generate(), at=0.0)
simulate(until=100.0)
```

Output:

```
 0.0000 Customer00 (original) enters server A
 5.0000 Customer00 (original) leaves server A
10.0000 Customer01 (original) enters server A
15.0000 Customer01 (original) leaves server A
20.0000 Customer02 (original) enters server A
25.0000 Customer02 (original) leaves server A
30.0000 Customer03 (original) enters server A
35.0000 Customer03 (original) leaves server A
40.0000 Customer04 (original) enters server A
45.0000 Customer04 (original) leaves server A
logout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid copy a Simpy Process is not such simple, I think because they are generators ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401610/python-copy-deepcopy-produces-an-error)) and because they hold internal variables for the simulation.

To make your code work you can modify RunA(self) as follow.
Here we create two new Process-Customers that look like self instead of copy it.

```
def runA(self):
    print("%7.4f %s (original) enters server A" % (now(), self.name))
    yield hold, self, 5
    print("%7.4f %s (original) leaves server A" % (now(), self.name))

    dup1 = Customer(name = self.name)
    dup2 = Customer(name = self.name)

    activate(dup1, dup1.runB())
    activate(dup2, dup2.runC())
```

This works well because you have only one variable to copy. In more complicated cases you can [use the var(Object)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109087/2389570) method but be aware that the Process class holds many variables you probably shouldn't copy.

Also, I recommend [this tutorials](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/python.html) on SimPy to help you design your simulation.

Comment: Yes, do not try and use a deepcopy or copy function, as these new Processes will not be activated or registered within SimPy. You can quite easily make Processes spawn other Processes - so make the Customer Process self spawnable.